# @firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.0.4): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an Angular 6 project. This is the error I get when I build with `--prod`
flag, host and run.
I've been sitting on this for a long time. Initially thought it was probably a problem with the firestore package and i waited.
But now updated to firestore 5.0.4, the problem still exists.

> [2018-06-04T06:11:47.859Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.0.4): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
>
> This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

app.module.ts

```
Imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule
]
```

app.component.ts

```
constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
          private afs: AngularFirestore,
          private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this._currentUser = this.afAuth.authState
      .pipe(
        switchMap((user: any) => {
           if (user) {
            console.log(user);
            return this.afs.collection('users').doc<User>(user.uid).valueChanges();
           } else {
             return Observable.create(null);
           }
        })
      );
}
```

FYI: Authentication still works.

dependencies
firebase 5.0.4
angularfire2 5.0.0-rc.10

Comment: In Github there is an opened issue https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/901

Answer (score 10):

You should enable Firestore in you Firebase Console. Do the following steps:

1. **Open** the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), open or create a new project.
2. In the **Database** section, click the **Get Started** button for **Cloud
   Firestore**.
3. **Select** a starting mode for your Cloud Firestore Security Rules: **Test mode** or **Locked mode**
4. Click Enable.

Cloud Firestore and App Engine: **You can't use both Cloud Firestore and Cloud Datastore** in the same project, which might affect apps using App Engine. Try using Cloud Firestore with a different project.
When you create a Cloud Firestore project, it also enables the API in the **[Cloud API Manager](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/apis/api/firestore.googleapis.com/overview)**.

Comment: You were my savior. Thanks. This helped me.

Comment: i will try this, i have RTDB and firestore in same project

Answer (score 9):

I was having problems with my **Kaspersky antivirus** and **AdBlock Chrome plugin**

***Possible problems:***

- Slow internet connection
- Antivirus/Firewall related problem (blocking)
- AdBlocker problem (blocking too)

Comment: Thanks. Kaspersky was blocking the firestore for me. After disabling Kaspersky, the problem was resolved. Tested this on 4 desktops running kaspersky where the same issue was present.

Comment: Thanks it was Antivirus/Firewall related problem (blocking)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this randomly in both dev and production, this solved it for me.
Set this to true:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Settings#optional-experimentalautodetectlongpolling

You will need at least version 7.24.0 of the JS SDK.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#cloud-firestore_13

Here's how to do it using AngularFire:
In app.module.ts (or other module that imports AngularFire).

```
 providers: [
    { provide: FirestoreSettingsToken, useValue: { experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling: true } }
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I just change the private network to public network

- open setting windows setting
- click network and sharing or check your network if it is private change to public may solve your problem

[windows 10 network and sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfNI4.png)

Answer (score 0):

This might help :)

Import only `AngularFirestoreModule` even if you are using the other modules such as the `AngularFireStorage` or `AngularFireDatabase`.

Not sure why but I have used this approach in many projects with no problems ;)

```
// Angular Fire Modules in my projects using auth, firestore, realtime db, & storage

AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
AngularFireAuthModule,
AngularFirestoreModule,
```